# Does the output sequence of `std::sample()` follow the order of the input sequence?

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, c++17

Does the output sequence of `std::sample()` follow the order of the input sequence?

For example,

```
const std::vector<int> input{2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7};
std::vector<int> output;
std::sample(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(output), 3, any_urbg);
```

Is it guaranteed that `output` would never be possible to be `[1, 2, 3]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference on [`std::sample`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) states:

> The algorithm is stable (**preserves the relative order of the selected elements**) only if *PopulationIterator* meets the requirements of *LegacyForwardIterator*

The *PopulationIterator* here the iterator of `std::vector`.
The iterator of `std::vector` is a [*LegacyRandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator)  which satisfies the type of [*LegacyBidirectionalIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator) which in turn satisfies the type of [*LegacyForwardIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator).

So, yes, **it is guaranteed** that output would never be possible to be `[1, 2, 3]` because that would violate the relative order of the selected elements which would be `[2, 1, 3]`.

Answer (score 1):

From [std::sample](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) :

> *The algorithm is stable (preserves the relative order of the selected elements) only if PopulationIterator meets the requirements of LegacyForwardIterator*

Answer (score 0):

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample:

> The algorithm is stable (preserves the relative order of the selected elements) only if `PopulationIterator` meets the requirements of *[LegacyForwardIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator)*

In your case, `PopulationIterator` is `std::vector<int>::iterator`, which is indeed a *LegacyForwardIterator* (and in fact a *[LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator)*), so, yes, the elements should have the same element in `output` as they had in `input`.